# Can I run a Report Server and a Mirror server from a working Log Shipping secondary instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, mirroring, ssrs, log-shipping

Our setup:

- City A - Primary server for logshipping
- City B - Secondary server for logshipping

Now there is a lot of data being updated from A - B.

And the server in City B is underutilized, and it is a very powerful machine.

Can I install a Reporting server and a mirroring server on the server which hosts the secondary *logshipping* server, and run the Reporting and mirroring server to get the data from the sSecondary logshipping server?

We cannot have the data come across 3 times (one for Logs, Report, Mirror) - and the secondary server is updated regularly enough to allow for our requirements.

But the secondary logshipping server is obviously always in Standby/Readonly mode - is this all possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "mirroring server"? This question is very confusing.

Comment: If you are going to go to the trouble of setting up mirroring between City A and City B (which is what I'm guessing that the OP means), what does the log shipping get you?

Comment: want to setup Mirroring from the secondary log shipping server in City B --> to a mirror instance of it. I'm told to do it, so I have to make this work somehow unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is confusing but I think what you're trying to say is that you want to access the data at City-B, using your existing log-shipping setup.

1. With regards to the log shipping, at City-B, there is an option [RESTORE ... WITH STANDBY] which will leave the database in restoring mode, however in a READONLY state so it's accessible for SELECT queries. The main restriction with this approach, is that you can only restore a log when all users are out of the database. Depending on your log shipping restore schedule (very frequent/this may not work then), you'd have to kill all the
   connections prior to restoring the next log. Test this and re-do your log shipping config.
2. Depending on your version of SQL, perhaps explore using DB Snapshots at city-B - need to research how this would interact log shipping.
3. You could install/configure Reporting Services at City-B (which would create the two system report databases). Reports could then query the databases (at city-b) which are involved in log-shipping (but read-only) as per my first point.
4. If you going to create another instance on City-B, then how about creating a job that performs a backup of databases on City-B (instance1/logshipping) and restoring on City-B (instance2/Reporting Instance) - which you can then access as required.
5. Mirroring does not let you read from the mirrored instance.

I hope this helps.